# Browser on submit with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

On submit of a form I show a blocking message "Please wait" with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('form').submit(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: "<h1 id='waitingmessage'>Plz wait ...</h1>" });
  });
});
```

That works ok for me.

If the user presses F5 now, the browser ask for resubmit. The user is allowed to.
But the script above does not trigger anymore.

How can I trigger this resubmit with jquery, thus the waitingmessage is still shown?

Thx

Chris

EDIT:
The submit of the form goes to the same adress as the form. I only distinct on the controller side between GET and POST. If it was a POST, I process the received data, otherwise I show only the blank form.
The user is allowed to send data twice or as often as wanted. So after the first POST the user can press F5 to resubmit the data, and he is totally allowed to.
It's just that the waitingmessage does not appear any more.
So I need maybe a more general solution "onpost". Does something like that exist?

SOLUTION:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('form').submit(function() {
      $.blockUI({ message: "<h1 id='waitingmessage'>Bitte warten ...</h1>" });
   });

   $(window).keydown(function(event){
      if (event.keyCode == '116' && '${request.method}' == 'POST') {
         $.blockUI({ message: "<h1 id='waitingmessage'>Bitte warten ...</h1>" });
      }
   });
});
```

And request.method is set server side and is either 'GET' or 'POST' thus I know where the user came from.

Comment: Do I understand? This page is opened by POST type request, and when user try to refresh page browser ask him to resend POST data? And after reload the script don't run ?

Comment: Maybe I have to clear up something. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I don't have perfect solution too. I will do only for only first `F5` event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{
    $(window).keydown(function (e)
    {

        if(e.keyCode == 116){
            submitform();
            return false;
        }
        alert(e.keyCode);
    });
})

function submitform()
{
    alert("hello");
}
</script>

<form id="myform" action='test.php'>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="submitform(); return false;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok thats the right direction. I'll post my solution in the question.

Comment: @Waxolunist thanks for acceping and voting up ... didn't expected it

Comment: It doesn't always have to be the full fledged working power solution. A good hint is often better. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't, because when the user press F5, the browser make a refresh of the last "Query" and the last Query is the POST of the form, not the display of the form.

In your history, you have something like this :

- GET : showForm.php     (Form with JS code)
- POST : sublitForm.php  (Form processing)

When you press F5, the browser perform a refresh on the POST.

EDIT: You can perhaps make a HACK, using an Ajax call or using `$('#myForm').submit();`. And after the result, use a `location.href` to redirect the user.

If the user perform an refresh, you'll don't have the post in you sequence.

Answer (score 0):

[Using jquery to prevent resubmitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831464/using-jquery-to-prevent-resubmitting-form)  chech this link